# How to map continuous variable to color in plotnine?

Tags: python, python-ggplot, plotnine

I'm trying to map a continuous variable to color in plotnine. In R, I can do this by setting color param to `log(pop)`. In plotnine, I tried this alternative, and it generates this error:

> ValueError: Image size of 300573x430 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

```
from gapminder import gapminder
import math
p = ggplot(data=gapminder, mapping=aes(x='gdpPercap', y='lifeExp'))
(p + geom_point(mapping=aes(color=[math.log(v) for v in gapminder['pop']]))
   + scale_x_log10()
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an expression in a string. In that string you can refer to columns in the dataframe and variables in the environment. And it is simpler use vectorized functions from `numpy` rather than the `math` module.

```py
from gapminder import gapminder
import numpy as np

p = ggplot(data=gapminder, mapping=aes(x='gdpPercap', y='lifeExp'))
(p + geom_point(mapping=aes(color='np.log(pop)'))
   + scale_x_log10()
 )
```